# Bash script for setting up mac keeps skipping commands or simply prints to the console without executing lines

Tags: bash, macos, homebrew

I've been trying to create a bash script that allows me to transfer my existing dev setup to a brand new macbook.

I set up a bash script which is supposed to automate this process but for some reason when I call the script using curl, it doesnt seem to reliably run the whole thing and I cant figure out why that is. [example of commands being printed to the console and note executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUGax.jpg)

If I were to manually enter each line into the terminal and execute, things work as expected however doing so defeats the purpose of the script.

I'll attach some screenshots of the terminal output so you can see the exact issues I'm facing and at which point it behaves oddly.

I've had to run the script a few times to get it to execute the skipped steps but it would be good to understand why certain steps are getting missed. Here's a link to [my gist](https://gist.github.com/curtis-j-campbell/b695513a44393c3a5084c011c6d0c890) containing the script. Would appreciate any suggestions for improvements or explantations for the behaviour I'm seeing.

Things I have tried that havent resolved my issue:

- Splitting the script into two smaller scripts
- Erasing my mac and running the script again (done this several times)
- Adding `sleep 5` between each command

edit: this is how I'm running the script

```
sudo curl -Lks https://gist.githubusercontent.com/curtis-j-campbell/b695513a44393c3a5084c011c6d0c890/raw | /bin/bash
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You say you're running the command via curl. Please show what you're doing.

Comment: Hi, just added the curl command I've been using

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, but if the curl-pipe you posted here, does not do what you expected, wy don't you run it then with `/bin/bash -x`, to see what's going on?

Comment: Also, I would consider using `-S` instead of `-s` for curl.

Comment: @user1934428 I wasnt aware of these flags, I'll try them asap, thanks

Answer (score 2):

It appears that everything after `brew install git` is being echoed. That suggests that something in that command is copying its stdin to stdout, so it's processing the rest of the script. Change that line to

```
brew install git </dev/null
```

so it won't read the script as its stdin.

Also, you don't need to run `curl` under `sudo`. If you need privileges to install the program, you should run `bash` as the superuser, not `curl`.

```
curl -Lks https://gist.githubusercontent.com/curtis-j-campbell/b695513a44393c3a5084c011c6d0c890/raw | sudo /bin/bash
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I'll format my machine and try with the suggested changes. One of the problems is the screenshot in the original post shows the script behaving oddly after running `brew install git`  but this isn't consistently happening after that command

Comment: A more general problem is that shell scripts don't generally expect the script itself to be in standard input. When you run a shell script, it normally inherits the caller's stdin.